# PHP, how to set a string variable as "</a>"? PHP thinks it is command.

Tags: php, html, string

I am just trying to write a simple page, where I create a clickable link for HTML.

I get the first part okay, but this part yields a blank string:

```
$URLString = "<";
$URLString .= "/a";
$URLString .= chr(62); // that is, ">"

echo "URLString = ";
echo $URLString;        // shows blank space
```

Any idea how to get PHP to accept this as a string, and not a command?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Let's see, you're echoing html tag, what it should do?

Comment: You want to *see* it?

Comment: I think I understand what he want

Comment: you just don't see it since you're viewing it on a browser, right click view page source, you'll see it

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you well, and I think I have, you want to use:

```
$URLString = "&lt"; //that is "<"
$URLString .= "/a";
$URLString .= "&gt"; // that is, ">"

echo "URLString = ";
echo $URLString;        // shows blank space
```

This are characters that represend < and > for html. Which is what htmlentities internaly does and you can find that in PHP docs

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

Here is a link http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 1):

You should use **htmlentities()**:

```
        $URLString = "<";
        $URLString .= "/a";
        $URLString .= chr(62); // that is, ">"

        echo "URLString = ";
        echo htmlentities($URLString);
```

Comment: `echo` can be used with a comma btw to output several things at once.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you would like to display a link on your page if I were you I would close out of the php and just write the html. For example

```
<?php
    //Some actual php code would go here
?>
<a href="www.google.com">Look where this takes you!</a>
```

If you just close out of the php the php parser will just output whatever text is there. You can even generate some dynamic stuff in your php code and easily output it using the `<?= ?>` tag in php. Like this:

```
<?php
    $tagText = 'Look where this takes you!';
    $tagHref = 'www.google.com';
?>
<a href="<?= $tagHref ?>"><?= $tagText ?></a>
```

Both of these blocks of code produce the same output.

Also like everyone else is saying in the comments, you wont be able to see just an `<a>` being sent to the browser. The browser doesn't display tags, it ***usually*** displays what is between an open and closing tag.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/ for more info on all of this stuff and some great tutorials.

Comment: You mean that my "$URLstring" variable *is* holding the "</a>" string, the "echo" function just doesn't display it?

Comment: If you are viewing it from a browser then yes. Most browser support viewing the source, which will show you exactly what was sent to the browser. Right click and then press "view page source" (chrome, firefox) or "view source" (Edge) to see the tag.

Comment: Would you recommend making this a Function? simple LinkFunction('TextHere','URLHere'); ?